# I already have my report viewer work on my forms but there is another error

Tags: reporting-services, report

I upgraded from VS 2015 to Vs 2022 and downloaded the Report Viewer/RDLC Designer extension . Now when I report viewer, go to Report Viewer Task, click Design New Report the following error comes up: Error invoking 'Design a new report'. Details: Method not found: 'EnvDTE.Document EnvDTE._DTE.get_ActiveDocument().

Can someone please help me to fix this error. I have uninstalled the extension and reinstalled, Cleaned and Rebuild.

Thank you